# Using JdbcCursorItemReader and IN clause in the SQL query

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am developing a spring batch application and using the chunk based processing.

For Reader i am using the `org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader` class.

When configuring the Reader and specifying the SQL property, how can we use the combination of `preparedStatementSetter` to set values for an `IN` clause in the SQL?

My SQL:

```
select * from Employee where employeeId IN (,,,,,,).
```

How can I dynamically set the values for `IN` clause using `preparedStatementSetter`?

Comment: did you find the answer?